# Select at least one li validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have form in jsp, which have UI,li listing as drop-down view
So, while submitting form I want to check atleast one li should be selected else form will not get submit.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). Add a custom method or customize the submit handler for the check